# App Center Build Crashing After Upload to Play Store

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I used (like always) the MS App Center for my release build, and the build APK I created with the MS App Center, works on 32-bit and 64-bit devices. But after uploading to the Play Store-through the App Releases (in Release Management) or even through Internal App Sharing (in Development Tools), the app crashes on launch. The app worked after I downloaded it from the MS App Center when tested it. But when I tried to install the app from the Play store, it crashes and does not even show the first screen.

What I tried:

- I tested the app from my computer and that worked great in the release mode too when I deployed it to the device or emulator directly. I wished it didn't work so that I would be able to diagnose what the issue was, but there were absolutely no exception thrown.
- I have read and searched a lot of different posts, but none of those worked. I tried to play around with Dex, linker, shrinker, embed in native assemblies, even making the app as big as possible and adding multidex, but nothing works.
- In fact, I even took the code of the older version that was published successfully on the play store, but that caused a crash on launch as well. I used multiple Macs to replicate this error and multiple 64 bit & 32 bit devices to test.
- Just to test it, I download the published Play Store APK and uploaded it to the Play Store again, but that APK worked.

[Here's](https://privatebin.net/?0d7424718bba67f8#AJSpaBZiYLcDLwxTPXsbZzv4PZGCqZbAh76JUKYjk2YS) my Stack Trace that I got using `adb logcat` of my 32 bit test device. All the logcat were extremely similar.

For those who can't open the pastebin, here's a summary:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bgrs.reloaccess, PID: 29347
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) [0x0001a] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00016] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x0000e] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Version.TryParseComponent (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] component, System.String componentName, System.Boolean throwOnFailure, System.Int32& parsedComponent) [0x0000b] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Version.ParseVersion (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] input, System.Boolean throwOnFailure) [0x0011a] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Version.Parse (System.String input) [0x00014] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at System.Version..ctor (System.String version) [0x00014] in <915e1956390a4a4c9eeb4e5a86a3b84f>:0 
  at ReloAccess.Droid.LoginActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x000cf] in <34564626c64d48b5bf58d931504c2b9e>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <8354d046afcb48708fb91f153e8a8cb8>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.12(intptr,intptr,intptr)
    at md5eb9edb947e2683f0feaecf2c0d709827.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md5eb9edb947e2683f0feaecf2c0d709827.LoginActivity.onCreate(:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity
```

The Version.Parse happens in [this function](http://%20%20https://ybin.me/p/2269813e2244b28e#upIJ57NNee7RYhmU6EB7zG1p1X42fLdX9oE5XiCi9SI=).

Comment: Are you using "System.Version.Parse" in your code?

Comment: Yes i do, not one that i added though, its an older codebase. It says:      if (systemStatusResponse.Count > 2 && Version.TryParse(systemStatusResponse[2], out currentVersion))     {      systemStatus.CurrentVersion = currentVersion;     }

Comment: @SushiHangover I have added the entire function at the bottom of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out why the bug only displayed after uploading to the Play store, I even made sure that the API was not deprecated.

After @SushiHangover's suggestion though, I tried to remove the TryParse Version code, but I noticed that the bug was not there, it was here instead:

```
AuthenticationManager.Instance.AppVersion = new Version (this.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo (this.PackageName, 0).VersionName);
```

When I went through the usage of the PackageManager.GetPackageInfo in the native Java/Kotlin, I noticed that users used a Try-Catch for this as it doesn't seem very stable and tends to raise "NameNotFoundException" that can crash the app. So you should try to be safe and assume that GetPackageInfo raises an exception. You definitely can't TryParse an exception, so here's a possible solution:

```
try
{
    PackageInfo pInfo = PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(PackageName, 0);
    var version = pInfo.VersionName;
    if (Version.TryParse(version, out Version result))
    {
        AuthenticationManager.Instance.AppVersion = result;
    }
    else
        AuthenticationManager.Instance.AppVersion = new Version(4, 13, 17);

    Console.WriteLine("Version Name : " + version);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NameNotFoundException: " + ex.Message);
    AuthenticationManager.Instance.AppVersion = new Version(4, 13, 17);
}
```